# Why applying acpc alignment in MATLAB and brainlife results in different affine of the acpc aligned MRI images?

Tags: matlab, affinetransform, mri

I have applied acpc alignment of a set of MRI images in MATLAB (https://github.com/vistalab/vistasoft/wiki/ACPC-alignment) and in brainlife(https://brainlife.io/app/5b96d5ed059cf9002719250b with MNI152_1mm The 1mm MNI_152 as the template)

the affine and shape of output of acpc alignment in MATLAB are:

[[1,0,0,-90],

[0,1,0,-126],

[0,0,1,-72],

[0,0,0,1]]       181x217x181

the affine and shape of output of acpc alignment in brainlife are:

[[-1,0,0,90],

[0,1,0,-126],

[0,0,1,-72],

[0,0,0,1]]       182x218x182

Could anyone help me figure out why these two are not the same please?
thank you in advance